# Homestead YAML Directory

Tags: vagrant, homestead

I have an issue with the Homestead VM directory. My homestead.yaml file has the following folder/sites setup:

```
folders:
- map: ~/web/sites
  to: /home/vagrant/web

sites:
- map: test.app
  to: /home/vagrant/web/test/public
```

They're all in the same root directory (F:) and when I SSH into the VM and use the "dirs" command I don't see any folders in there. Thanks!

[image]

UPDATE:

The file sync works fine now and I can see my files/folders in the VM directory. Now, my issue is the IP routing. In my hosts file I put in the IP which is at the top of the YAML file (see below) but when I go to test.app:8000 is get the error shown in the last image. The file path for my project on the host machine is C:/users/matt/web/sites/test which is the same root directory as the homestead folder. Your help is REALLY appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case closed, I had somehow created a separate .txt file of the original hosts file. So, I thought I was editing the correct hosts file but wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

> Without options, **dirs** displays the list of currently remembered
>   directories.  The default display is on a single line with directory
>   names separated by spaces.  Directories are added to the list with the
>   pushd command; the popd command removes entries from the list.

so unless you push the directories to the list, they would not appear.

you should be able to access `/home/vagrant/web` and see your content there